# How do I verify this identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I verify the identity:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)=\cos x?$$
Please give the steps on how you got your answer.

Comment: This may depend on the definitions you use for sine and cosine (and $\pi$)

Answer (score 7):

We have by [the Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)=\Im \left(e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)}\right)=\Im\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{ix}\right)=\Im\left(ie^{ix}\right)=\cos x$$

Comment: Spot on, Sami!!

Answer (score 4):

Remember

$$ \sin( \alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha $$

$$ \therefore \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} + x \right) = \sin \frac{\pi}{2}\cos x + \sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 1 \cos x + \sin x \times 0 =\cos x $$

Answer (score 2):

If you have the graph of $y=f(x)$, the graph of $y = f(x +a)$ may be obtained by translating the graph of $y=f(x)$ left by $a$. You can readily apply this principle here. Make a simple sketch and the answer is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=-t$ then you have to the co-function identity $\sin( \frac{\pi}{2} - t )=\cos t$, remember $\cos(-t)=\cos t$ being an even function.

Answer (score 1):

pretty easy:

$ \sin ( \pi/2 + x ) = \cos ( \pi/2 - \pi/2 - x) = \cos (-x) = \cos x $